Does Nifi use ephemeral storage in Kube for some internal process
We have our Nifi is deployed on a kubernetes pod as a statefulset. All flowfile repository, provenance and content repo sits with NFS. Usually the ephemeral storage utilization stays at 800-900MB but when event consumption is high at times we have seen ephemeral storage go upto 5GB to 10GB.
I have checked exec into pod and check the df usages, but they seem constant. But the kubernetes pod throughs ephemeral usage differently.
In cases of multi pod, two pods show same df utilization but when I check the ephemeral limits they have a difference of 100-150MB.
Could someone help with what I might be missing ?
